# In what chapter of the manga does Mitsuhide sneeze because Obi was talking about him?

Tags: snow-white-with-the-red-hair

I'm looking for the chapter in the manga where Mitsuhide sneezes because Obi was talking about him.
**Edit**; possibly when Obi was in Lyiras...and after Mitsuhide sneezed, he said something like, "i had a feeling that somebody said something really rude about me." and Zen replied with Kiki," it was probably Obi." 
Apparently, it was a superstitious sneeze!
Thank you if you can find the chapter for this funny extract! Simply because I would like to read that part again!

Comment: This is a pretty common trope. Do you have any other details else for better context?

Comment: This is on-topic (I think) but I'm curious as to why you'd want to know when a particular character sneezed.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. Chapter identification is on-topic if you can explain more context, mention the reference, or state why you believe this happens. Based on previous experiences, someone asked a reference to a scene which is apparently from a fandom/fan-fiction, means it never happens on the official anime & manga, and it ended badly.